# Is it expected behavior that path is reset between requests in a single Scenario?

Tags: karate

I'm trying to create a vanilla delete test, and our endpoints check Etags. The proper way to go about this IMHO is:

1. GET the object & read its etag header
2. Assign that header to the etag header in a follow up DELETE request

So I have something like this:

```
Feature: Delete with etag

Background:
    * url config.url
    * path 'path/to/entity/type'

Scenario: Retrieve Login page url     
    Given path entityId
    When method get
    * def etag = responseHeaders['Etag']

    Given path entityId
    And header Etag = etag
    When method delete
    Then status = 204
```

This seems like it should work, but what I'm seeing is that between the two requests the root path set in the Background is reset. Is this expected? It makes sense if the assumption is that if you are making multiple requests within a scenario, the subsequent requests could be to a different url, and resetting the path is necessary to avoid polluting it for the secondary host (since path is append-only).

As a follow-on, this is a pretty common scenario in my experience. Is there a better usage pattern to handle this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1):

Simple, you just shape the "base URL" to match your REST "resource". `url` will *not* be re-set. `path` is.

```
* url config.url + '/path/to/entity/type'
```

And now this will work as you expect:

```
Given path entityId
```

The [Hello World example](https://github.com/intuit/karate#hello-world) shows this pattern if you look closely.

Comment: Nice. I had settled on storing the root path in a variable (also defined in Background), but that might be even nicer.